# Matlab: how to save in a "light" format?

Tags: matlab

I have a code which constructs a big Matlab numerical array that I would like to save. This array is a cell of size `10^4 x 1174`. Each subcell is a row vector of size `1x80000`.

Can I store and save the numbers in this array in a "light" way? For instance, I wonder if saving in txt would help. Do you have any suggestions?  I use Matlab R2019b.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the format of the numerical array you are trying to save? You mention it's a "numerical array" but then refer to "cell size": are you creating a ```10000x1174``` cell array that contains a ```1x80000``` vectors in each cell?

Comment: What is “light”? Simple to implement? Small file size? Quick to write or read?

Comment: with MATLAB `double` precision by default, your array needs `8*80000*1174*10000=7.513x10^9 bytes`. That is **~7 Tbytes** for one object. I am surprised that your computer can even handle such an array in memory. If you want to go lighter you could start by converting everything that can be in types with smaller sizes. Floating point numbers from `double` to `single` and convert every integer in the lowest integer type possible.

Comment: The Matlab .mat format does compress data for storage (using zlib). How does it perform with your monster array?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can save your large array in a "light" way in MATLAB:

1. Use the `save` function with the `-v6` flag: This will save your array in a binary format that is more compact than the default format. You can use the following code to save your array:

> save('filename.mat', 'array', '-v6')

2. Use the `dlmwrite` function to save the array as a delimited text file: This can be a good option if you need to be able to read the data in other programs that do not support the `.mat` format. You can use the following code to save your array as a tab-delimited text file:

> dlmwrite('filename.txt', array, 'delimiter', '\t')

3. Use the `sparse` function to convert your array to a sparse matrix: A sparse matrix is a matrix that has a lot of zero elements, and it can be stored more efficiently than a full matrix. You can use the following code to convert your array to a sparse matrix and `save` it using the save function:

> sparse_array = sparse(array);
> save('filename.mat', 'sparse_array', '-v6')

Comment: `-v6` has no compression, I believe? Are you sure it’s a more compact form than a newer MAT file?

Comment: For 3: please clarify that this does not reduce the number of non-zero values in the array, it is a more efficient storage if the array has lots of zeros.

Comment: The `dlmwrite` option is not going the "light" way. With an array of this size it is going to produce unimaginely large text files which are going to be very unwieldy. It probably wouldn't fit on any FAT32 partition for example (max file size=4GB).